# Dynamically Create Props

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

How do you dynamically create props from a mixin / lifecycle hook in vue?

I have tried the following:

```js
function install(Vue, Options) {
    Vue.mixin({
        beforeCreate: function() {
            this.$options.props = {
                name: {
                    type: String
                },
                age: {
                    type: Number
                },
                gender: {
                    type: String
                }
            }
        }
    })  
}

const PropEditor = {install}
module.exports = PropEditor
```

but the code above does not work.  I have also tried using this.props = {...   and that also does not work.

I have stepped through each line in the debugger and had a close look at vue's internal init functions but I am unable to work out why the props are not setting.

The reason I would like to dynamically edit props is I would like to create a plugin that allows  us to use a more advanced prop definition syntax with stricter validations on the props themselves.  The way this would work is by setting another property on the components such as inputs, which would then be processed in the beforeCreate to create the props property.

Comment: you can access vm.$attrs

Comment: @Estradiaz i'm not sure how to use vm.$attrs to set the props

Comment: The short answer is check github vue src, but basically everything that is not assigned in props will stay in attrs, thus you can grab those at runtime and set them to the vm instance etc, but check how props work in source ;)

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/98b4d683f578bb09c4e56f35048e49441c590a41/src/core/instance/state.js#L64 and lastly where everything happens

Comment: Ok hmm yours schould actually work ??

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but I tested it many times and it doesn't

Comment: If i put a console.log it runs.. and I can step through using the debugger but it never sets the props

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint here https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/98b4d683f578bb09c4e56f35048e49441c590a41/src/core/instance/state.js#L51 ? As before create ist called first and you assign props it should arrive here?

Comment: OK so I tried that... still couldn't get it to work.  I think it might have something to do with propsData in initProps

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to add the props in `beforeCreate`, declare `props` in your mixin object:

```js
Vue.mixin({
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String
    },
    age: {
      type: Number
    },
    gender: {
      type: String
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The props need to be generated so I need to call it from within a function

Answer (score 0):

Like you noticed and my first comment mentioned: its about `vm.$attrs`:

```
beforeCreate(){
  this.$options.props = {propName: {}};
  this.$options.propsData = this.$attrs;
}
```

but be aware that you need to delete those props from attrs to stay consistent with vue, e.g:

```
Object.keys(this.$options.props).forEach(key => this.$attrs.hasOwnProperty(key) && delete this.$attrs[key])
```

hope this helps ;)